# Getting error Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in my code

Tags: php, mysqli

Getting error Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in

```
  <?php

    include 'includes/config.php';
    include 'includes/database.php';
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);



    if (isset($_POST['sign'])) {
      $name=$_POST['email'];
      $pass=$_POST['password'];
      $query_two="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user='$name' AND password='$pass' ";
      $runn=$db->query($query_two);

      $row_login=$runn->fetch_assoc();

    if ($row_login['user']==$name && $row_login['password']==$pass) {
      session_start();

      $_SESSION["username"] = $name;
      header('Location: adminpane.php');
      exit();

    }

    else {
      echo "<script>
    check();

      </script>

      ";
      exit();


    }


    }


     ?>
```

> this is in  my database.php file

```
<?php
$db=new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
?>
```

> this is in my config.php file

```
 <?php

define('DB_HOST', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'XXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXX');
define('DB_NAME', 'myDB');


 ?>
```

> I am including both at the top,but still it doesnt seems to work!!,
>   everything username password is correct and the code was working on
>   local host

Comment: There is not a single call to `mysqli::query()` so at least some relevant code is missing. Btw you are vulnerable to SQL injections ...

Comment: I have added the code ,please check again!!

Comment: Now that you have published you DB connection details (username, password), please DO CHANGE THEM AT ONCE. Otherwise you will have some visitors in your database pretty soon.

Answer (score -1):

Use something as :

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'includes/config.php';
include 'includes/database.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['sign'])) {
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
  $query_two = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user='$name' AND password='$pass'";
  $runn = mysqli_query($db,$query_two);
  $row_login = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runn);

  if ($row_login['user']==$name && $row_login['password']==$pass) {
   $_SESSION["username"] = $name;
   header('Location: adminpane.php');
   exit();
  } else {
   echo "<script>check();</script>";
   exit();
 }
}
?>
```